# Text isn't centring on min-height image

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm struggling to find the best way to centre my text in the middle of the image (vertically and horizontally). The problem I'm having I think is that the image I have set has a min-height property. The min height property changes in tablet and mobile compared to desktop. Can anyone think of a solution to centre it and have it be responsive?

```css
.home-section-image {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/814499/pexels-photo-814499.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    opacity: .80;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 840px; 
    
    /* Create the image scrolling effect */
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 69px;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 1.5px;
    text-align: center; 
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 6.2vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 4.6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {
  
  .centered-image-text {
    top: 34%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 740px; 
  }
  
  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 5vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  
    .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 360px;  /* May change back to original height: 100%; */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/814499/pexels-photo-814499.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    margin-top: 61px;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    top: 18%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 8vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  }
```

```html
<section id="home" class="home-section">
      <div class="home-section-image">
      <div class="centered-image-text">
        <div class="centered-text1">PositiveTalkwithTC</div>
        <div class="centered-text2">CBT Therapist</div> 
        <div class="centered-text3">Random Text</div> 
      </div> 
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: To get a feel for what the problem is, if you look at this: http://nathan-bayne.co.uk/index1 This is what is happening when I resize the window to the smallest possible width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your problem, you can solve this using flexbox, some things of your code isn't necessary to get this result.

Here is what i did:

I added these properties to the parent element of the text elements `.home-section-image`:

```css
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

I removed all `transform`, `left` and `right` properties from children elements `cenetered-text*`

This will keep the text just on the center of the parent (which is `.home-section-image`)

**Obs.:** This only works because the parent has a specific heigth.

```css
.home-section-image {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    /* The image used */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/814499/pexels-photo-814499.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    opacity: .80;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 840px; 
    
    /* Create the image scrolling effect */
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 69px;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 1.5px;
    text-align: center; 
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 6.2vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 4.6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {
  
  .centered-image-text {
    
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 740px; 
  }
  
  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 5vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  
    .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 360px;  /* May change back to original height: 100%; */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("../images/testmobile.jpg");
    margin-top: 61px;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 8vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  }
```

```html
<section id="home" class="home-section">
      <div class="home-section-image">
      <div class="centered-image-text">
        <div class="centered-text1">PositiveTalkwithTC</div>
        <div class="centered-text2">CBT Therapist</div> 
        <div class="centered-text3">Random Text</div> 
      </div> 
      </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `.home-section-image` to `position:relative`

```css
.home-section-image {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/814499/pexels-photo-814499.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    opacity: .80;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 840px; 
    
    /* Create the image scrolling effect */
    /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-top: 69px;
    position:relative;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 1.5px;
    text-align: center; 
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 6.2vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 4.6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 4vw;
    font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1606px) {
  
  .centered-image-text {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 740px; 
  }
  
  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 6vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 5vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  
    .home-section-image {
    /* Set a specific height */
    min-height: 360px;  /* May change back to original height: 100%; */
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.15), 
      rgba(8, 8, 8, 0.35)
    ),url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/814499/pexels-photo-814499.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    margin-top: 61px;
  }

  .centered-image-text {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #BCE4B8;
    -webkit-text-stroke: black 2px;
    text-align: center;
  } /* Edits text overlaying image positioning, colour of text and adds stroke */

  .centered-text1 {
    font-size: 10vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the first line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text2 {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
  } /* Edits sizing and margin of the second line of text displayed over the image */

  .centered-text3 {
    font-size: 8vw;
  } /* Edits sizing of the third line of text displayed over the image */
  
  }
```

```html
<section id="home" class="home-section">
      <div class="home-section-image">
      <div class="centered-image-text">
        <div class="centered-text1">PositiveTalkwithTC</div>
        <div class="centered-text2">CBT Therapist</div> 
        <div class="centered-text3">Random Text</div> 
      </div> 
      </div>
</section>
```